# How can I modify my BibTeX template?

Tags: bibtex

I am using a modified BibTeX template from Elsevier; see [this](https://github.com/lichengzhang1/BibTeX_template) (link provided since it is too long),

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

 For instance, 1-planarity cannot be characterized in 
terms of forbidden minors \cite{grigoriev2007algorithms}. 
For a graph with $n$ vertices, it is possible to determine in linear time 
whether the graph is planar or not \cite{hopcroft1974efficient}, even for the 
graphs formed from planar graphs 
by adding a single edge \cite{korzhik2013minimal}. 

\bibliographystyle{e}
\bibliography{my.bib}
\end{document}
```

my.bib:

```
@article{grigoriev2007algorithms,
  title={Algorithms for graphs embeddable with few crossings per edge},
  author={Grigoriev, Alexander and Bodlaender, Hans L},
  journal={Algorithmica},
  volume={49},
  number={1},
  pages={1--11},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Springer}
}
 @article{hopcroft1974efficient,
  title={Efficient planarity testing},
  author={Hopcroft, John and Tarjan, Robert},
  journal={Journal of the ACM (JACM)},
  volume={21},
  number={4},
  pages={549--568},
  year={1974},
  publisher={ACM New York, NY, USA}
}
@article{korzhik2013minimal,
  title={Minimal obstructions for 1-immersions and hardness of 1-planarity testing},
  author={Korzhik, Vladimir P and Mohar, Bojan},
  journal={Journal of Graph Theory},
  volume={72},
  number={1},
  pages={30--71},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

[image]

But I have found that the journal's requirements are as follows (they provided BibTeX style document seems not suite  requirement), see the file (namely 468198_LaTeX_DL_468198_01072021.zip) in [this](https://github.com/lichengzhang1/BibTeX_template):

[image]

The main difference is as follows:

- the order of the author's last name and first name, with the last name preceding the first name.
- the last author is terminated with a colon instead of a comma.
- The volume number is in bold.
- The year is placed at the end, enclosed in parentheses

I'm a beginner in BibTeX, and I currently have only one template at hand. If modifying the template is challenging, are there any similar templates available? I've also looked at some other templates， for example, abbrv or acm, but they always seem too different

**Note that:** I just find `spmpsci.bst` in their file is ok.

Comment: Two quick comments: (a) Don't include the filename extension .bib in the argument of `\bibliography`; (b) does the journal provide a bst file to simplify implementing their, to put it politely, somewhat uncommon formatting requirements?

Comment: If the journal doesn't provide a suitable bst file, you may be better off not modifying an existing bst  file and, instead, creating a new bst file from scratch with the help of the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib). package

Comment: I'm adjusting some wording. The journal I am preparing to submit to is under Springer, 'Graphs and Combinatorics.' They provide a BibTeX style file, but it seems that none of them conform to the journal's standards.

Comment: Sorry, I just see spmpsci.bst is ok